# Update from DataGridView with SqlDataAdapter

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, triggers, sqldataadapter

I have a DataGridView that displays data from a SQL Server database. It allows the user to edit the data and save it back to the database.

The way that data gets saved back to the database is something like this:

```
Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
Dim cmdBuilder As New SqlCommandBuilder(da)

da.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, conn)

da.InsertCommand = cmdBuilder.GetInsertCommand

da.UpdateCommand = cmdBuilder.GetUpdateCommand

Dim cb As SqlCommandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(da)
da.Update(dt)
```

This works fine when I'm saving to ordinary tables. However I also want to save to a view that has an INSTEAD OF trigger that fires on insert, update and delete. When I try to use the above with this view I get the error:

Dynamic SQL generation for the UpdateCommand is not supported against a SelectCommand that does not return any key column information.

How can I save to this view? I don't want to save directly to the underlying table because I want the trigger to fire.

Thanks!

EDIT: I also tried manually generating the InsertCommand and UpdateCommand, but got the same error.

EDIT 2: It turned out I got the commands wrong when I manually generated them. Once I fixed that it worked fine - my view gets updated and the trigger fires as expected. I guess that you just can't autogenerate the commands for a view with SqlCommandBuilder.

Comment: does your table have a primary key column ?

Comment: The underlying table does have a primary key. I wondered if SqlDataAdapter wasn't picking it up because I was pointing at the view not the table. I'm also now thinking that I may have got the commands wrong when I tried to write them manually, so I'll have another go...

Answer (score 0):

a quick google search shows that this problem may occur if your table does not have a primary key value. your select query must return that value for the update query (in a case where there is no primary key column, it wouldnt.)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-NZ/Vsexpressvcs/thread/5dec5633-ac84-48d9-8fd6-5c7601be4ccd